# Multiply input values into other input

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I want to multiply numbers and the result shows in another input.

I managed to obtain the value of each input with the following code, but from here I do not know how to advance and make it multiply and that the result is shown in the input of the "total".

This is part of the code:

```
$(`
        [name='unidadTrabajosFactura'], 
        [name='precioUniTrabajoFactura'],
        [name='totalTrabajoFactura']
        `).each(
            function(index, item){
                
            var valores = $(item).val();
            console.log(valores)

        });
```

in the console I get the following results:

[image]

What I want to achieve is that the quantity value is multiplied by the unit price and show the result in in input of total

An this is my form code

```
 <div class="job-form row mb-3">

<div class="col-md-1">
    <label for="unidadTrabajosFactura" class="">Unidad</label>
    <input type="text" name="unidadTrabajosFactura" class="form-control" value="{{trabajo.unidad}}">
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="descTrabajosFactura" class="">Descripción</label>
    <input type="text" name="descTrabajosFactura" maxlength="200" class="form-control" value="{{trabajo.trabajo}}">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="precioUniTrabajoFactura" class="">Precio Unitario</label>
    <input type="text" name="precioUniTrabajoFactura" class="form-control" value="{{trabajo.precio_unitario}}">

</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="totalTrabajoFactura" class="">Total</label>
    <input type="text" name="totalTrabajoFactura" class="form-control" value="{{trabajo.total}}">
</div>
```

These fields can be multiple as well as one

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through `job-form` div and inside each loop use `.find()` to get required input values and add total inside your total inputs.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//loop through form divs
$(".job-form").each(function(index, item) {
  //get values..
  var units = parseInt($(this).find("[name=unidadTrabajosFactura]").val());
  var price = parseInt($(this).find("[name=precioUniTrabajoFactura]").val());
  //add total to required input
  $(this).find("[name=totalTrabajoFactura]").val(units * price)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="job-form row mb-3">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <label for="unidadTrabajosFactura" class="">Unidad</label>
    <input type="text" name="unidadTrabajosFactura" class="form-control" value="10">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="descTrabajosFactura" class="">Descripción</label>
    <input type="text" name="descTrabajosFactura" maxlength="200" class="form-control" value="Something...">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="precioUniTrabajoFactura" class="">Precio Unitario</label>
    <input type="text" name="precioUniTrabajoFactura" class="form-control" value="2">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="totalTrabajoFactura" class="">Total</label>
    <input type="text" name="totalTrabajoFactura" class="form-control" value="{{trabajo.total}}">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="job-form row mb-3">
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <label for="unidadTrabajosFactura" class="">Unidad</label>
    <input type="text" name="unidadTrabajosFactura" class="form-control" value="10">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <label for="descTrabajosFactura" class="">Descripción</label>
    <input type="text" name="descTrabajosFactura" maxlength="200" class="form-control" value="Something..">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="precioUniTrabajoFactura" class="">Precio Unitario</label>
    <input type="text" name="precioUniTrabajoFactura" class="form-control" value="3">

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="totalTrabajoFactura" class="">Total</label>
    <input type="text" name="totalTrabajoFactura" class="form-control" value="{{trabajo.total}}">
  </div>
</div>
```